# Dropdown is showing behind the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div and inside that div there are some buttons with a drop down, wrapper should have a max-height and an auto scroll.

The problem is if I click on a button, now the drop down always will be placed behind the wrapper, is there way to get the drop down on top of the wrapper

[jsbin link](http://jsfiddle.net/t4dfu713/)

```css
.bs-example
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    margin: 30px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bs-example">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: set position fixed and top auto in `.dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed; top:auto;}`

Comment: @Awais it's not working, do you have an updated bin?

Comment: i added my answer

Comment: It's not showing behind the parent, it's inside the parent (the parent becomes scrollable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go a working snippet here

```css
.bs-example
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    margin: 30px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Default <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> You can set `left` as well for align to left of div, I also use `!important;` to override bootstrap default styles.

Comment: @bews99 Glad to hear that it helped. Cheers

Comment: here, in the answer you provided, if you scroll down to bottom and press the button, then the menu is not placing in the proper place, how I can fix that?

Comment: @bews99 ill work on it and let you know when i came up with the solution, for now i can say that we need to use some JS script to handle that case